# this id program to change decimal to binary, what is the error here?

Tags: java

decimal to binary

error:

```
C:\Users\i\Desktop\17.12.2013>javac bin2dec.java
bin2dec.java:20: non-static method print(int[],int) cannot be referenced from a
static context
print(array,i);                        ^
1 error
```

code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class bin2dec
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("No");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[20];
        int i = 0;
        while (n < 0)
        {
            array[i] = n % 2;
            n = n / 2;
            i++;
        }
        print(array, i);
    }

    public void print(int array[], int i)
    {
        for(int j = i-1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            System.out.print(array[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make that method static `public static void print(int array[], int i)` or you can create object of the class and call print method. I would encourage the use of proper coding conventions. Class names should start from capital letter

```
Bin2Dec converter = new Bin2Dec();
converted.print(array,i);
```

You cannot reference a non-static method from a static context.

- A static method is bound to class itself. It is accessed using class name.
- A non-static method is bound to an instance of the class.
- As non-static is not bound to a class hence it cannot be called directly from static context.

Answer (score 2):

The method `print` must be static if you want to call it from a static context.

```
public static void print(int array[], int i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling non-static method in your main method, create an object of your class in your main method and call with it.

e.g.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class bin2dec
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            bin2dec object = new bin2dec();
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("No");
            int n=input.nextInt();
            int array[]=new int[20];
            int i=0;
            while(n<0)
            {
                array[i]=n%2;
                n=n/2;
                i++;
            }

            object.print(array,i);

        }
        public void print(int array[], int i)
        {
            for(int j=i-1; j>0; j--)
            {
            System.out.print(array[j]);
            }
        }
}
```